# JSP Web Application Will Not Insert Data Into A Database Using NetBeans And MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, netbeans, insert

I am trying to insert data into my database using NetBeans. The connection is working fine. I have tried another project using SELECT data and it worked fine but my INSERT data code is not inserting data and I can't find in my code where the problem is. The solutions ID is auto increment which is why I did not include that in my insert statement.Here is my code:

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Insert Solutions</title>
    </head>
    <body onload="displayResults()">
        <h1>Insert Solutions</h1>
        <%!
            public class Backup {

                String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/solutions";
                String user = "root";
                String pass = "t3i3n3a3";

                Connection connection = null;
                PreparedStatement insertBackups = null;
                ResultSet resultSet = null;

                public Backup() {

                    try {
                        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);

                        insertBackups = connection.prepareStatement(
                                "INSERT INTO backup (backup_name, backup_issue, backup_solution)"
                                + "VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                public int setBackups(String first, String second, String third) {

                    int result = 0;

                    try {
                        insertBackups.setString(1, first);
                        insertBackups.setString(2, second);
                        insertBackups.setString(3, third);
                        result = insertBackups.executeUpdate();
                    } catch (SQLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();;
                    }
                    return result;
                }
            }
        %>
        <%
            int result = 0;

            if (request.getParameter("submit") != null) {
                String firstName = new String();
                String secondIssue = new String();
                String thirdSolution = new String();

                if (request.getParameter("first") != null) {
                    firstName = request.getParameter("first");
                }
                if (request.getParameter("second") != null) {
                    secondIssue = request.getParameter("second");
                }
                if (request.getParameter("third") != null) {
                    thirdSolution = request.getParameter("third");
                }
                Backup backup = new Backup();
                result = backup.setBackups(firstName, secondIssue, thirdSolution);
            }
        %>

        <form name="myForm" action="index.jsp" method="POST">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Backup Name :</th>
                        <th><input type="text" name="first" value="" size="50" /></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Backup Issue</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="second" value="" size="50" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Backup Solution</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="third" value="" size="50" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>   
            <br>
                 <input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="<%= result%>" /> 
            <input type="reset" value="Clear" name="clear" />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
    </form>    

    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JaavaScript">
      
           function displayResults()
        {
            if (document.myForm.hidden.value === 1) {
                alert("Data Inserted!");
            }
        }
        
    </SCRIPT>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was able to connect to the database and insert data but the alert is now not working. So it's an alert issued because the data is being inserted but I'm not getting the notification of the event being successful.

Answer (score 0):

Another question answered. It was the value in the Javascript function. when I changed the `=== 1` to `==1` it worked!